BillAdd request can't find sub-accounts on QuickBooks Desktop
I'm trying to perform a BillAdd request on QuickBooks Desktop using their SDK, but the AccountRef of the expense lines can't seem to find sub-accounts by name. I don't have the List ID so I need to be able to search by name, and I am able to do it successfully for accounts, but when it comes to sub-accounts I get the following error message:

There is an invalid reference to QuickBooks Account "My sub-account" in the Bill.  QuickBooks error message: Invalid argument.  The specified record does not exist in the list.

Is there a workaround for this? Do I need to know the account whom it belongs to?
Thank you

Update – I was able to find the answer here thanks to someone who helped me on the Intuit Developers blog:

For object instances that are in hierarchies, it is necessary to
include the sequence of parent-to-child relationships that form a path
to the object instance, therefore, for these object instances, the
fullname, much like a file path, concatenates the names of the parents
and the instance to form a unique identifier. Within one of these
fullnames, each name is delimited with a colon:
Brian Cook:Home:Kitchen:Sink

